# how to make if-elif-else statement work properly in a function to print patterns in Python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, design-patterns, return-value

I wrote a program (1) that prints my name in patterns (each letter in the name is made of its letters that makes a pattern). I am trying to modify it to be inside a function instead (2). I have read some stuff on docs.python.org, but I cannot find enough information to do it correctly. At this point, Python does not print anything at all, not even an error. Just a blank page.
Here is my original code that works well and prints RISH (see pix I attached - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ7SG.png)):

### 1

```
String = '';
for row in range(0,8):    
    for column in range(0,30):
        if (column == 0 or row == 0 or column == 29):
            String =String + '*'
        elif (column == 2 or ((row == 1 or row == 4) and column > 2 and column < 6) or (column == 6 and row != 1 and row < 4) or (column == row - 1 and row > 3)):  
            String = String + 'R'
        elif (column == 11 or (row == 1 and column > 8 and column <14) or ( row == 7 and column > 8 and column <14 )):  
            String =String+'I'
        elif (((row == 1 or row == 4 or row == 7) and column > 16 and column < 20) or (column == 16 and (row == 2 or row == 3 or row == 7)) or (column == 20 and (row == 1 or row == 5 or row == 6))):  
            String = String + 'S'
        elif (column == 23 or column == 27 or row ==4 and (column>23 and column <27)):
            String = String + 'H'
        else:      
            String = String + ' '    
    String = String + '\n' 
print(String)
```

What I am trying to do is to place my "if-elif-else statement" into a function and returns pattern. Could anyone help me understand if I need to define something before the statement in order for it to return the pattern or there is something else has to be written after each statement? Because the else statement (String = String + '\n') is very important to print the pattern and I have no clue how to modify it.
Grazie! Thanks a bunch!

## 2

```
def printName(string = ''):   

    for row in range(0,8):    
        for column in range(0,30):
            if (column == 0 or row == 0 or column == 29):
                return '*'
            elif (column == 2 or ((row == 1 or row == 4) and column > 2 and column < 6) or (column == 6 and row != 1 and row < 4) or (column == row - 1 and row > 3)):  
                return 'R'
            elif (column == 11 or (row == 1 and column > 8 and column <14) or ( row == 7 and column > 8 and column <14 )):  
                return 'I'
            elif (((row == 1 or row == 4 or row == 7) and column > 16 and column < 20) or (column == 16 and (row == 2 or row == 3 or row == 7)) or (column == 20 and (row == 1 or row == 5 or row == 6))):  
                return 'S'
            elif (column == 23 or column == 27 or row ==4 and (column>23 and column <27)):
                return 'H'
            else:      
                return ' '    
        String = String + '\n'
       
printName()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you were missing about functions is that when a function reaches a return statement it immediately stops the function and exits. So really you just need to take your original code and indent it under a def statement.

Also, since your function is only meant to write one name it is unnecessary to provide the string argument in the function call. You can create the string within the function's scope. Since the function isn't generating anything that you want to keep in memory a return statement isn't required.

```
def printName():
    String = ''
    for row in range(0,8):    
        for column in range(0,30):
            if (column == 0 or row == 0 or column == 29):
                String =String + '*'
            elif (column == 2 or ((row == 1 or row == 4) and column > 2 and column < 6) or (column == 6 and row != 1 and row < 4) or (column == row - 1 and row > 3)):  
                String = String + 'R'
            elif (column == 11 or (row == 1 and column > 8 and column <14) or ( row == 7 and column > 8 and column <14 )):  
                String =String+'I'
            elif (((row == 1 or row == 4 or row == 7) and column > 16 and column < 20) or (column == 16 and (row == 2 or row == 3 or row == 7)) or (column == 20 and (row == 1 or row == 5 or row == 6))):  
                String = String + 'S'
            elif (column == 23 or column == 27 or row ==4 and (column>23 and column <27)):
                String = String + 'H'
            else:      
                String = String + ' '    
        String = String + '\n'
    print(String)


printName()
```

The above code should provide what you are after.

If you wanted to return the resulting string from your function you could do the following:

```
def printName():
    String = ''
    for row in range(0,8):    
        for column in range(0,30):
            if (column == 0 or row == 0 or column == 29):
                String =String + '*'
            elif (column == 2 or ((row == 1 or row == 4) and column > 2 and column < 6) or (column == 6 and row != 1 and row < 4) or (column == row - 1 and row > 3)):  
                String = String + 'R'
            elif (column == 11 or (row == 1 and column > 8 and column <14) or ( row == 7 and column > 8 and column <14 )):  
                String =String+'I'
            elif (((row == 1 or row == 4 or row == 7) and column > 16 and column < 20) or (column == 16 and (row == 2 or row == 3 or row == 7)) or (column == 20 and (row == 1 or row == 5 or row == 6))):  
                String = String + 'S'
            elif (column == 23 or column == 27 or row ==4 and (column>23 and column <27)):
                String = String + 'H'
            else:      
                String = String + ' '    
        String = String + '\n'
    return String


name = printName()
#now the string is in the variable name, outside of the function's scope.
print(name)
```

Comment: oh so I didn't have to use actual "return" after all but my actual code. Thank you so much for your help! It works now :)

Comment: No problem. I added an additional option that shows how you might use a return statement in the function, and how it is different than the first option of not using a return.